# Iterate through List using ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am testing if I iterate correctly trough my list of results. To do this i created a `PartialView` which creates a new `Div` with the word 'Nice'. As you can see in the image I know for sure that there are 100 results but it seems that the `Foreach` loop doesn't work. Should I iterate in a different way?

[image]

Webresult:

[image]

## Code:

### Controller (FeedController.cs)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult _Feed()
    {
        return PartialView(getStatusses());
    }

    private List<LinqToTwitter.Status> getStatusses()
    {
        //Code to get tweets
    }
```

### View (Index.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
    @{ 
        Html.Action("_Feed");
    }
</div>
```

### PartialView (_Feed.cshtml)

```
@model List<LinqToTwitter.Status>

<div id="FeedPosts">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            Nice
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It should be working as expected. What issue you are having ?

Comment: @haim770 thanks for your quick answer. I didn't realise there was a difference between `@ { Html.Action("_Feed") }` and `@Html.Action("_Feed")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `Html.Action()`, you need to instruct Razor to append the results of the action to the output using the `@` symbol:

```
@Html.Action("_Feed");
```

Otherwise, it simply returns an `MvcHtmlString` that you don't use.

This applies even when the call is made inside a code block (`@{...}`):

```
@{
    @Html.Action("_Feed");
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: The surrounding `@{    }` is not really necessary

Comment: @StephenMuecke, It's only there to demonstrate than even though you already in a `@{...}` block, you still need the other `@`.